# Swift class-property update

Tags: swift, class, properties, object-reference

So I have to pass instance of my custom class from one `UIViewController` to another:

```
targetVC.reservation = self.reservation!
print(self.reservation!.id, "before")
targetVC.reservation!.phoneNumber = self.phoneTextField.text!.phoneToString()
targetVC.reservation!.id = id
print(self.reservation!.id, "after")
```

My problem is that `self.reservation!.id` is also changed: "*before*" it is `""`, and "*after*" it is `id`. Why does it happen and how to avoid this?

Comment: More code is needed before we can help you.

Comment: what exactly do you need? cause my problem is that `targetVC.reservation!.id = id` also updates `self.reservation!.id`

Comment: Classes are ref type. so whenever you are assigning the `targetVC.reservation!.id = id` it is also changing the `self.reservation.id` value. Both pointing to the same object.

Comment: Yeah, my guess was something like this. How should I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`mutableCopy()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1418978-mutablecopy) with your object but for that your custom class need to extends from `NSObject` and its return type is `Any` so you need to explicitly type cast its result to your `CustomClass`.

```
targetVC.reservation = self.reservation!.mutableCopy() as! YourCustomClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Classes are ref type. so whenever you are assigning the `targetVC.reservation!.id = id` it is also changing the `self.reservation.id` value. Both pointing to the same object. If you don't want to change the `reservation.id` value when `targetVC.reservation!.id` changes you can create copy of your class using `mutableCopy` but your class needs to extends `NSObject` as @Nirvad D said or you can use `Structures` which is value types.

You can go to documentation for further reading [Classes and Structures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html)