# Why does the value in this dictionary change?

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdictionary

I've been trying to debug something in my code and came across this. You can put this directly in `playground`.

```
import UIKit

class testObj {
    var prop1: Int?
}

var testObjInst = testObj()

var myDic : [String : testObj] = [:]

testObjInst.prop1 = 1
myDic["A"] = testObjInst
testObjInst.prop1 = 2
myDic["B"] = testObjInst
testObjInst.prop1 = 3
myDic["C"] = testObjInst

print(myDic["A"]?.prop1) //prints 3

if let myVal = myDic["A"] {
    myVal.prop1 = 5
}

print(myDic["A"]?.prop1) //prints 5
```

How is the `myVal` variable changing the value for `myDic["A"]`? Shouldn't `myVal` be assigned to the result of calling `myDic["A"]` and the return of this call would ultimately be a new instance of the object?

Edit 1: My segues are performed like this:

```
    if segue.identifier == segueIDs.air {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? PointsTableViewController {
            //these are the dictionaries. 
            vc.rewardProgramsDic = rewardProgramsDic
        }
    }
```

The issue I've been getting is when a property was set in the `destination` `viewController`, when I would press `back` and print the values in the `rewardProgramsDic` the values would have changed. I tried setting `breakpoints` on the `rewardProgramsDic` as well as using `didSet` to try and catch the change but neither of those is called when a property is updated in the `destination` `viewController`.

Edit 2:

In the originating `viewController`:

```
var rewardProgramsDic: [String: IndividualRewardProgram] = [:]
```

In the destination `tableViewController`

```
var rewardProgramsDic:  [String: IndividualRewardProgram] = [:]
```

Comment: Because all keys are pointing to the same instance of testObj. Compare with this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/41343905/6433023

Comment: you need to hardcopy the instance to assign it to myDic

Comment: Thanks both of you. This definitely helped. One question on the keys pointing to instances of `testObj`. If I were to pass this `dictionary` in a `segue` - does the `destination's` `viewController's` instance of this `dictionary` also point in memory to the same place? I.e., a change in the `destination` `viewController` would change this `dictionary` if I were to press the `back` button?

Comment: @Sami No That will not happen, try once running it you will know.

Comment: :( guess that means my bug is something else.

Comment: @Sami Can you show how you are passing value in `prepareforsegue`.

Comment: Thank you @Nirav. I just updated my question to include how I pass values in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `rewardProgramsDic`? May be you are still changing the value of same instance.

Comment: @nirav added the declaration on edit #2

Comment: I have check your code this will not change value of `rewardProgramsDic` from ViewController dic when you changed in destination controller because it is value type not reference type, you are probably change its value some where else.

Comment: @Nirav - sorry to get back so late, I've been trying to debug this issue over the last few days. Through further investigation it looks like the objects in the dictionary are actually being passed in the segue through reference type - and they are not being passed by value.

Comment: @Sami Have you solved it or not?

Comment: Yes! The issue was the dictionary objects shared the pointer in memory in both the parent VC and the destination VC. See my answer below. Your discussion on here was immensely helpful though, thank you for the patience, much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you are getting such result because you are using **Class**.

> Class is reference types & reference types are not copied when they
>   are assigned to a variable or constant, or when they are passed to a
>   function.

Mean by updating object value, will updates all the instances where they actual assigned. Here in above example,

```
testObjInst.prop1 = 1
myDic["A"] = testObjInst // myDic["A"]?.prop1 :- 1
testObjInst.prop1 = 2
myDic["B"] = testObjInst // myDic["B"]?.prop1 :- 2 & myDic["A"]?.prop1 :- 2
testObjInst.prop1 = 3
myDic["C"] = testObjInst // myDic["C"]?.prop1 :- 3 & myDic["B"]?.prop1 :- 3 & myDic["A"]?.prop1 :- 3

if let myVal = myDic["A"] { //So Here, myDic["A"]?.prop1 :- 3
    //Here, myDic["A"] class instance is assigned to myVal object, 
    //So changing value in myVal object directly reflect in all object.
    myVal.prop1 = 5 // myDic["A"]?.prop1 :- 5 & myDic["B"]?.prop1 :- 5 & myDic["C"]?.prop1 :- 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this function:

```
func address<T: AnyObject>(o: T) -> Int {
    return unsafeBitCast(o, to: Int.self)
}
```

and calling it the `parent view controller`, like this:

```
print(NSString(format: "%p", address(o: rewardProgramsDic["ID1"]!)))
```

and then calling this same function in the `destination view controller`, I confirmed that the `parent view controller` and the `destination view controller's` variables were pointing to the same place in memory. This explains why I was getting the cascading down change explained with my conversation with @Nirav.

Thank you both for your responses.

Comment: Marking @Sagar's response as the answer and not mine since it really was the focus of the question.